# Asynchronous images loading from the web in Cocoa

Tags: cocoa, asynchronous, nsimage

I am looking for a way to easyly load images from the web in Cocoa (for mac, not iOS)

Any pointer?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NSURLConnection is the Cocoa API for the job.

However, some people prefer ASIHTTPRequest (I'm one of them) so you should check that out too. The developers of this library have really good docs as well!

Answer (score 2):

I know this is late to answer, but i made a NSImageView subclass to downloads images asynchronously. It's the PVAsyncImageView.
Check it out here: [PVAsyncImageView](https://github.com/pedrovieira7/PVAsyncImageView)

Answer (score 0):

`CGDataProviderCreateWithURL` can be used to create a `CGImageRef`. using this, you shouldn't have to set up with your own url connections (but you should not call it in realtime or from the drawing thread because it will block).

once you have a `CGImageRef`, you can either use the result directly or use it to create an `NSImage`.